# What AI algorithm to use to find hidden shapes in a Battleships-like game

Tags: ai

I'm developing a game similar to Battleships, only using different shapes. A single type of shape will be used within a game session, by both the human player and AI. There will be several objects spread out on the map (10x10 grid).

I want to find a way to guess the location and position of the human player's "ships" after I have one or more hits.

I'm aware that there will be a lot of randomness involved, but I want the AI to be smart enough to pose a challenge to the human player.

I'm thinking about having the AI "sweep" the map and evaluate each possible shape, somehow assign a probability to a certain position and maybe refine the guess by additional sweeps (thus a higher difficulty). But I need some ideas on what logic to use, I don't want to check every possible combination.

Thank you.

Comment: There is only one type of ship. There are multiple ships (probably 3) with the same shape.

Comment: Have the ai randomly select a cell.  If that cell is a hit (depending on difficulty of ai) have it next check a cell between (x - 1, y - 1) and (x + 1, y + 1).  Again based on how smart you want it to be you could randomly make it try to check random cells again.  rinse repeat .

Comment: Thank you, but that's exactly what I want to avoid. I agree that it works, but it takes a lot of moves. I would use this approach to first have at least 2-3 hits. But then I want use a smarter way to guess the position and orientation of the "ship".

Comment: I'd suggest waiting at least a day to accept an answer. It often encourages more people to answer and improves the available answers.

Comment: agreemsg :) esp when there's no "one right answer"

Comment: @Byte56, yes, I know, but this answer is good enough for me. I intend to add the finished solution here, so it may help other people.

Comment: For future reference, there's an [excellent article on Battleship algorithms on DataGenetics](http://datagenetics.com/blog/december32011/index.html), which should be possible to adapt to different piece shapes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds similar to polyomino puzzle solving, which I've played with...

With a 10 x 10 grid, you can reasonably do an exhaustive search for each shape.

Starting from the top left, and going to the lower right, try to set the shape onto the grid. If it contradicts one of the known misses, discard it. If it overlaps some of the known hits, rank it as more likely.

Do this for each shape at each orientation.

Some cells might be members of several possible shapes, so that square could be considered even more likely.

By the end, you could have a ranking on each of the 10 x 10 cells.

Comment: Hmm. This sounds like what I need. I don't have to do an exhaustive search. As soon as I get a successful hit,  I can start searching around it. After I kill the ship, I continue with the remaining successful hits or try to (semi-randomly) hit other ships. Setting the shape onto the grid will help me eliminate zones that can't contain a ship (using information from successful or unsuccessful hits).

Comment: You're comment seems to assume that the best strategy is to work on one ship at a time. Maybe it is... interesting problem

Comment: Well, it may be better to work on all of them at once, but I don't know. Considering this is a  turn based game, I don't see much reason to handle more than one ship at a time. This is the way it's played by human players, most of the time, anyway.